# How do I manually sort articles?

Tags: nodes

I need to know of a way to manually order the articles displayed in the Drupal 8 front page by displaying a title between each piece. For example,

**Title A**

Article 2 
Article 5 
Article 3

**Title B**

Article 1 
Article 7

I've tried configuring the front page view and looked into the Drupal 8 article and basic page settings but couldn't determine an effective way by which the above could be achieved. I also looked into whether there are any featured content modules available to suit my above needs but couldn't find any. And also the content needs to be able to be added to any page (not just the front page) as well.

If you anyone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: EntityQueue module?

Comment: Yes, I would say [Entity Queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityqueue) is your best option here. @Kevin if you expand your hint into an answer, you get my upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `Title a,Title b` could be **terms** of a vocabulary
- add this vocabulary as term reference to article
- edit your nodes to include desired term
- modify front page view to group by term on this vocabulary

to have specific sorting for each of the term articles you can add integer field `position` to article and use it as sorting criteria in the view

for ordering the terms sort them in the vocabulary term list and use `term weight` as sorting criteria on view

For sorting one could also use [draggable views](https://www.drupal.org/project/draggableviews)  and even [nodequeue](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodequeue) as suggested in the comments